# WebView inside ViewPager inside NestedScrollView not scrolling vertically

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-webview, android-nestedscrollview

I need to enable webview scrolling that placed into viewpager that is in nestescrollview that is necessary because I'm using CollapsingToolbarLayout. But I cant scroll it. All works except WebView scrolling. Where I am wrong?

[image]

Here is my activity markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_read_article"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundLight"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ru.pwrg.revolution.activities.ReadArticleActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorBackgroundDark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/article_cover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                app:srcCompat="@color/colorBackgroundDark" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

WebView fragment for ViewPager markup:

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/article_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your `WebView` into a `NestedScrollView`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView android:id="@+id/article_webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

`NestedScrollView` works together with `CoordinatorLayout` and knows how to handle scrolls correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `fillViewport` and layout_behavior 1 times

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```